# How to plot Dataset

Tags: python, vector, machine-learning, nlp

Problem --- Clustering of english sentences.

Dataset --- Consists of English sentences.

Requirement --- For my interest I want to plot my data-set in a 2D or 3D graph before doing clustering.

What have i done so far --- I am working in python and have successfully created a sample-feature vector by using scikit CountVectorizer, where samples are english sentences and feature are set of words from these sentences.

`text=["machine learning", "Natural Language Processing", "Python and Vectors"]
vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=MyTokenizer(), analyzer = 'word')
fit_vec = vec.fit_transform(lines)
print fit_vec.toarray()`

> [[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
>
> [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
>
> [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
>
> [u'and', u'language', u'learning', u'machine', u'natural', u'processing', u'python, u'vectors']

I want to use samples and these vectors into a 2-D graph where y-axis is these vectors and x axis are samples. The problem comes in expressing these vector in a single value along y-axis. I want to choose some point of reference with which I can calculate distance/angle of every vector and use these values along y-axis.

I may be wrong in my observations since i am very little in knowledge. That's why i have came here for all clarifications.

Comment: Just to make it clear: "The problem comes in expressing these vector in a single value along y-axis" - you want a function which takes a binary vector, and return a natural number?

Comment: @AlexL- yes, u have got it right.

Comment: the most simple solution is to use  Euclidean distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).
Of course you can get same values for different vectors( d([0,1]) = d([1,0]) )

Comment: But, w.r.t to what should i take the euclidean distance?

Comment: to the zero vector: [0,0,0,0, ..]. In case v = [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0], you'll get
d(v) = d(v - 0) = sqrt( (0-0) + (0-0) + (1-0) + (1-0) + (0-0) + (0-0) + (0-0) +(0-0))  = sqrt(1+1) = sqrt(2)

Comment: does this works for you? If not, we can think about more sophisticated distance function

Comment: But there is one problem with this approach. Two vectors having same distance from zero vector but in different direction are not equal. How can I bring this difference into 2D.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120707/discussion-between-alex-l-and-rashmi-singh).